# step by step registration form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my html, that validates the input=[type] when the system detect empty it will not proceed in the next step, how do i disable it? because some of my field is not required.

For example the input type **`< input placeholder="Firstname" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MotherFirstname">`** is required and **`< input placeholder="Middlename" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MotherMiddlename">`** is not required. If the user fill out the firstname and not the middlename it will proceed to the next step,

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="landmark-formbuilder-0" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>Contact number *</strong></label>
         <input id="input" placeholder="Firstname" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MotherFirstname">
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="landmark-formbuilder-0" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>Middlename *</strong></label>
        <input placeholder="Middlename" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MotherMiddlename">
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="landmark-formbuilder-0" class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7"><strong>Lastname *</strong></label>
        <input placeholder="Lastname" oninput="this.className = ''" name="MotherLastname">
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("#input");

      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...

        if (y[i].value == "") {
          // add an "invalid" class to the field:
          y[i].className += " invalid";
          // and set the current valid status to false
          valid = false;
        }
      }

      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:

      if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
      }
      return valid; // return the valid status
    }
    </script>
```

This is the error in my web console:

[image]

From this line:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript don't need # or dot channge

```
y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("#input");
```

to

```
y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

also in your image, `getElementById("input")` if you set id as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `required` attribute in your html tags and it will be automatically required and you can leave the the ones you don't need empty.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbjrya45/2/